# There is any Java library to create Mime File Container?

Tags: library, java, http

I need to create a Mime File Container like this:

```
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----5nSasdfd5DQWERgOL732nyngX0hPJPPwasdfGptf8olMJTCQ=_1e_"

------5nSasdfd5DQWERgOL732nyngX0hPJPPwasdfGptf8olMJTCQ=_1e_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; name="document-text-1.xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

BP_Import_WsCreation
------5nSasdfd5DQWERgOL732nyngX0hPJPPwasdfGptf8olMJTCQ=_1e_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; name="document-text-2.xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<?xml ...>
<document>
....
</document>
------5nSasdfd5DQWERgOL732nyngX0hPJPPwasdfGptf8olMJTCQ=_1e_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; name="document-text3.xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<?xml ...>
<document>
....
</document>

end
------5nSasdfd5DQWERgOL732nyngX0hPJPPwasdfGptf8olMJTCQ=_1e_
```

This is a file input for an application. There is a java library for this, or any way to create this programatically?

Note: The code above is a very simple snippet only, the real file is more complex, this is the reason why I need a library.